# Generate Full URL ASP.NET MVC Razor Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to generate the full URL for a route link in my razor view for ASP.NET MVC 3.  I know I can use Html.RouteLink to generate a link however all I want is the URL, not the surrounding a tag wrapper.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.aspx).

```
 Url.RouteUrl( "MyRoute" )
```

Comment: This seems to work.  I used the RouteUrl(string, object, string) overload to generate the full url.

Answer (score 24):

Are you talking about:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { @id = "2" })">
    Link to Page</a>
```

vs.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link to page", "Action", "Controller", new { @id = "2" })
```

The `Url` Model builds only Links; `Html` builds the HTML as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RouteUrl` as [tvanfosson proposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306388/generate-full-url-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/6306408#6306408).

I would just want to mention [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC) adds the extension `ActionAbsolute` to create a full url from an action.